# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.ads.googleads.v10'

Tags: python, google-ads-api

We use a python script to connect to Google Ads API and consume its REST operations.

All of a sudden the working script has started giving error with below message:

```
from google.ads.googleads.v10.enums.types import offline_user_data_job_status
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.ads.googleads.v10'
```

Please advise.

Comment: did you install that module? Ans is your current version still v10?

Comment: Try `pip install google-ads`

Comment: google.ads.googleads.v12 - this works